# How to get value from popup filechooser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I got a popup filechooser from the below link:

[Kivy popup Filechooser pass variable (selection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386125/kivy-popup-filechooser-pass-variable-selection)

I cannot get the file path string value to pass between my main Tab() class instance of the app and the class FileChoosePopup popup instance.  I know this question has been asked before, but I cannot seem to figure it out.  When I run the app and click on the file I want to pass to a TextInput on my main class I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

I have tried passing a reference to the popup class instance in the main class by using the super init method, but then the app does not even initialize.

Here is my popup in python:

```
class FileChoosePopup(Popup):
    file_path = StringProperty("No file chosen")
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FileChoosePopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Tab = Tab()

    def load(self, selection):
        self.file_path = str(selection[0])
        path_file = self.file_path
        the_file = self.ids.get_file #is the textinput id

        if path_file != "No file chosen":
            the_file.text = path_file
            self.dismiss()
        else:
            self.dismiss()

class Tab(StackLayout):

    def open_popup(self):
        the_popup = FileChoosePopup()
        the_popup.open()
```

Here the kivy code:

```
<FileChoosePopup>:
    title: "Choose a .CSV File"
    size_hint: .9, .9
    auto_dismiss: False
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooser:
            id: filechooser   
            FileChooserIconLayout
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: (1, 0.1)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            spacing: 20
            RoundedCancelButton:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.dismiss()
            RoundedAcceptButton:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.selection)
                id: ldbtn
                disabled: True if filechooser.selection==[] else False
<Tab>:
    TabbedPanel:
        do_defualt_tab: False
        background_color: (.87, .87, .87, 1)
        border: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        background_image: 'path/to/background/image'
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Import'
            background_color: (1, .5, 0, 1)
            background_normal: ''
            StackLayout:
                orientation: 'lr-tb'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30
                spacing: 5
                Label:
                    text: ''
                    size_hint_x: 1
                Label:
                    text: ''
                    size_hint_x: 0.2
                RoundedButton:
                    text: 'Choose File'
                    size_hint_x: 0.2
                    on_press: root.open_popup()
                TextInput:
                    id: get_file
                    readonly: True
                    size_hint_x: 0.4
                Label:
                    text: ''
                    size_hint_x: 0.2
```

Can someone please give me some pointers on how to get the value to pass from the popup to the textinput?

Comment: I believed that there is some error(s) in your kv file. Please correct it.

Comment: @ikolim I fixed the indentation and missing class reference in kivy.  I only posted a snippet of the code, because I thought if more was needed someone would ask.  Thank you very much for your answer below as it solved my question.  I also marked it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Reference TextInput

Populate `TextInput` by using the following:

```
self.ids.get_file.text = self.file_path
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder


class FileChoosePopup(Popup):
    load = ObjectProperty()


class Tab(TabbedPanel):
    file_path = StringProperty("No file chosen")
    the_popup = ObjectProperty(None)

    def open_popup(self):
        self.the_popup = FileChoosePopup(load=self.load)
        self.the_popup.open()

    def load(self, selection):
        self.file_path = str(selection[0])
        self.the_popup.dismiss()
        print(self.file_path)

        # check for non-empty list i.e. file selected
        if self.file_path:
            self.ids.get_file.text = self.file_path


Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Tab()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
<FileChoosePopup>:
    title: "Choose a .CSV File"
    size_hint: .9, .9
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooser:
            id: filechooser
            FileChooserIconLayout

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: (1, 0.1)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
            spacing: 20
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.dismiss()
            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.selection)
                id: ldbtn
                disabled: True if filechooser.selection==[] else False

<Tab>:
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Import'
        background_color: (1, .5, 0, 1)
        background_normal: ''
        StackLayout:
            orientation: 'lr-tb'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            spacing: 5
            Label:
                text: ''
                size_hint_x: 1
            Label:
                text: ''
                size_hint_x: 0.2
            Button:
                text: 'Choose File'
                size_hint_x: 0.2
                on_press: root.open_popup()
            TextInput:
                id: get_file
                readonly: True
                size_hint_x: 0.4
            Label:
                text: ''
                size_hint_x: 0.2
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: How did you post a screen shot?

Comment: In Edit mode, 1) Pick the location to place an image / screen shot. 2) In the menu bar, click on the *Picture Frame* icon (aka *Image*). 3) Open your computer *File Browser / Manager*, select the image, ***drag and drop*** it into the dialog box containing, "*Browse, drag & drop, or paste an image or link*". 4) When image is uploaded, click button, "*Add picture*".

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: As a begginer to programming, this code taught me a lot about kivy in a very short time, Thanks !